# Treeview adding controls to outputted Root node

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am currently working on a project where i am required to add a button to the root node of the TreeView control, so it looks like this

[image]

currently to achieve this I do the following in the Node.Text property

```
treeNode.Text = string.Format("<span style=\"width: 220px; display: inline-block;\">{0}</span> <input type=\"button\" value=\"GO\" onclick=\"TreeRootGoButtonOnClick('" + tree + "','" + treeNode.Value + "','" + treeNode.Text + "')\" style=\"display:none; height: 20px; float:right;\" />", treeNode.Text);
```

This works as desired in IE but not in Chrome or any other browser as its firing the event for the Anchor tag that the button is sitting in, as below

```
<td class="TreeView_RootNode TreeView_Node" style="white-space:nowrap;">
    <a class="TreeView_RootNode TreeView_Node" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$uxMasterContentPlaceHolder$uxTreeViewCollaspsiblePanel$ctl00$uxTreeView','sCL^PA')" id="uxMasterContentPlaceHolder_uxTreeViewCollaspsiblePanel_ctl00_uxTreeViewt0" style="text-decoration:none;border-style:none;"><span style="width: 220px; display: inline-block;">Clients</span> <input type="button" value="GO" onclick="TreeRootGoButtonOnClick('Value1','Value2','Value3')" style="display:inline-block; height: 20px; float:right;"></a>
</td>
```

What i want to achieve is the following, where I can add the Button within the TD tag instead of within the anchor tag

```
<td class="TreeView_RootNode TreeView_Node" style="white-space:nowrap;">
    <a class="TreeView_RootNode TreeView_Node" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$uxMasterContentPlaceHolder$uxTreeViewCollaspsiblePanel$ctl00$uxTreeView','sCL^PA')" id="uxMasterContentPlaceHolder_uxTreeViewCollaspsiblePanel_ctl00_uxTreeViewt0" style="text-decoration:none;border-style:none;"><span style="width: 220px; display: inline-block;">Clients</span> </a>
    <input type="button" value="GO" onclick="TreeRootGoButtonOnClick('Value1','Value2','Value3')" style="display:inline-block; height: 20px;">
</td>
```

Any help would be appreciated i have tried googling an found nothing of any help so far.